# How to serve a random element so that each user gets the same random element in the same order?

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, server-sent-events

I am building an online radio station. I have created an XML database to store a *playlist* of song information so that users can be served a particular audio file, defined by the playlist (XML) in a predefined order; thus creating the illusion of a *show*. These shows are usually an hour in length. What I want to do is randomly generate song information after the show ends, to create an infinite, random playlist from my entire database. But a random song needs to be served to all users so that they each get the same experience (same song). It seems important to also illustrate how my shows are served in real time, as this sort of dictates how my *random generator* should work. To save time and space, I will omit certain functions of these features as thy can get rather lengthy. If you wish to see these omitted functions, I can submit them upon request. My initial thought to create this *random generator* was to use **SSE** (server sent events) but, maybe there is a simpler way.

I have a Javascript document which uses AJAX to query the database (playlist):

```
load_prs(track_data_complete , "playlist.xml") ;
```

`track_data_complete()` receives the response and updates the *audio player* with the current song info then makes another AJAX call to `timestamp.php`:

```
var current_play = 0 ; // current_play is global to indicate current song element in the playlist XML array
var track_length ; // Store current track length in seconds
var track_obj ; // object data for current song
var showtime ; // the shows beginning unix time
var timestamp ; // current unix time

function track_data_complete( XML )
{
var th = XML.children[current_play] ;
var band = get_val(th , "band") ; // get_val parses the XML data
var album = get_val(th , "album") ;
var title = get_val(th , "title") ;
var genre = get_val(th , "genre") ;
track_length = get_val(th , "length") ;
var tid = th.getAttribute("id") ;
var tsrc = "songs/" + tid + ".mp3" ;
track_obj = new tobj(band , album , title , genre , length , tsrc) ; // tobj creates a new object to store the data

showtime = Number(XML.getAttribute("showtime")) ;
load_prs(load_track , "timestamp.php?time=0") ;
}
```

`timestamp.php`

```
<?php echo ( time() + $_REQUEST['time'] . "" ) ; ?>
```

`load_track()` plays the song at a real time using the Unix timestamp returned by `timestamp.php` then updates the player with the song info:

```
function load_track( resp )
{
timestamp = Number(resp) ;
track_src.src = track_obj.tsrc ; // track_src is the audio element source
player_title.innerHTML = track_obj.band + " - " + track_obj.title ;
player_album.innerHTML = "Album: " + track_obj.album ;
track_audio.onended = function() { next_track() ; } ; // track_audio is the HTML audio element
track_audio.load() ;
begin_play() ;
}
```

`begin_play()` uses math to calculate real time to decide at what time to begin playing the audio. This simulates real time audio play. if the time exceeds the length of the first song then skip to next song until the current time is greater than `showtime`:

```
function begin_play()
{
swap("stop_track") ;
var time = timestamp - showtime ;
if ( time < track_length ) { track_audio.currentTime = time ; }
else { return next_track() ; }
track_audio.play() ;
}
```

`next_track()` increments `current_play` and adds `showtime` and current `track_length` together, then calls `track_list_complete()` again and starts this process over.

`playlist.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist auto="no" showtime="1526448420">
  <track id="funeral_doom_003">
    <genre>Funeral Doom</genre>
    <band>Depressed Mode</band>
    <album>Ghosts of Devotion</album>
    <title>Words of Silence</title>
    <length>3016</length>
  </track>
  <track id="funeral_doom_001">
    <genre>Funeral Doom</genre>
    <band>Evoken</band>
    <album>A Caress of the Void</album>
    <title>Descend the Lifeless Womb</title>
    <length>4270</length>
  </track>
</playlist>
```

NOTE: My entire database is in XML files. Each file is a genre of music. Since I have three genres, there are three XML files. The playlist file is separate because it gives me the ability to create shows. The playlist file and genre files are very similar in structure, the playlist lists most of the same data of a given song. At first glance, you think to just grab a random song from the genre database but, that will produce potentially different songs for each user. Similarly grabbing random songs from the playlist leaves out the rest of my database.

Comment: You mean server-sent-events, not x86 SIMD [tag:sse], right?  You *can* generate random numbers *very* fast with SSE / AVX ([What's the fastest way to generate a 1 GB text file containing random digits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324520) generates 1GiB of text digits in 0.03 seconds on a 3.9GHz Skylake CPU), but I you can't easily use it from Javascript.

Comment: Yes I meant server sent events.

Comment: The way I see it, my current design guarantees that users will all experience the playlist at the same time, well as close as possible. I'm not sure but, SSE seems like it will create more hassle. In theory, if I were to create a..... hold it... I think I just came up with an idea!!!

Comment: Never mind, the idea doesn't work.

Comment: Can you use a client-side PRNG to loop over the playlist in random order, and give every client the same seed so they all get the same infinite sequence?  That works as long as every client gets the same playlist to randomize.

Comment: Or generate numbers in a range client side and use those for requests, so the number -> playlist entry mapping happens server-side, and you don't have to send a complete playlist to the clients on any request.  The client just needs a PRNG seed and a range parameter so it can generate random numbers in the right range (matching how many total playlist entries you have).  That would maybe make it easy for someone to scrape your whole database, generating requests for each integer in sequence, though.

Comment: @Peter Cordes there is a problem with generating anything random client side. I need ALL users to get the same randomness. If one user gets a random number, say 13, then how are any other users going to get the same number, 13?

Comment: @Peter Cordes that is were XML comes in. With the info stored in a file, all users get the same info.

Comment: Use the same PRNG with the same seed to get the same sequence.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Periodicity.  Hard-code the seed into your Javascript.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I see now Create a seed that feeds into an algorithm, then fetch my songs accordingly. So I would log that seed into my playlist.xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171409/discussion-between-xavier-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a client-side PRNG to loop over the playlist in random order, and give every client the same seed so [they all get the same infinite of random numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Periodicity).  You could implement your own simpler PRNG, like a linear congruential generator, that generates every number once before there are any repeats, or you could just use the PRNG to feed a random shuffle algorithm.

You can just hard-code a seed value, like `42` into a .js, or put it in a `<script>` part of the php-generated HTML.  Or as you say, if the clients need to download an XML file anyway, put the PRNG parameters in there to let you easily edit the playlist file to get a different order.

You could even reduce the size of what clients need to download by *just* giving them PRNG parameters to generate random numbers in a 0..N range, and map those numbers to songs server-side.

Comment: Wow man, it really worked! I used a PRNG to generate a random number using a seed I stored in my XML playlist. Then I was able to use Javascript to play the random song but, in an order that every user gets, because the seed determiners the order of random numbers. What a brilliant idea! I know now it is nothing new but thank you so much. I also see that game designers use this approach as well. Saves having to get users to talk to each other.

Comment: NOTE: I noticed a lot of PRNG's out there do not explain a simple concept: Your random function needs to called by a method attached to the function, so that the result is fed back into itself, thus creating a sequence of random numbers. I had to write my own version of a PRNG to make the process happen this way. A lot of the ones I saw just show the function but, you don't get to see it in action, hiding that you have to feed the result back into itself. Your link to PRNG's on wiki helped me understand this concept. I was reading the history section.

Comment: @Xavier: Looks like tagging your question with a low-level tag like SSE was a lucky accident; I always liked to look under the hood and see how stuff worked at a low level, so I knew how computer programs generate random numbers.  Glad that helped.  And yeah, computer games do sometimes use deterministic code running on client and server (including a PRNG) to avoid sending the whole game state over the wire every step, just sending updates.  Deterministic floating point math is another very complex kettle of fish, though, because of compilers + C leaving some room for optimization. :P

Comment: unfortunately, my question was marked as too vague and put on hold. I reworded the question to be more specific. Hopefully that will help. Although once you read more into my question, it becomes clear. I think the hold can be removed now.

Comment: @Xavier: Well there are a lot of specific details that turn out not really to be needed.  The people that were looking at it as a PHP or JS question, rather than a simple algorithm / system-design question, probably saw it as too big to answer with actual code.  I was able to answer it succinctly because I've used PHP like once ever (to help a friend with an existing CGI script), and I only sort of know JS, so I didn't even think about trying to write an actual implementation, just describe how the pieces would fit together at a high level.  So yeah, voted to reopen because it's answerable.

Comment: That is why I used the term "approach" in my question. My question was not really language specific. It was definitely a design question. I only added my code examples to give an idea of where my code is going by design. Really it was all about the fact that I was using a unix timestamp to simulate real time.